# AWS - Cannot Connect To EC2 Server With Browser Using Public DNS/IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, server, ip

I'm fairly new to AWS and I'm trying to create an Amazon Linux server to run PHP code. I'm following the [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) on AWS, but I can't connect to my server using either the public DNS or IP address. The error I'm getting is "This site can't be reached. *Public DNS* refused to connect". The instance is currently running, and I've successfully connected to it using puTTy and WinSCP. I double-checked the security group for my server, and I have port 80 open to all IP addresses.

Comment: Do you have a Web server running on the instance? Did you open the security group? Did you open the firewall on the server's OS?

Comment: I followed the instructions to add web server functions to it, and I made the security group. Basically I've followed the instructions up to the point where it asked you to create a php info file, and then navigate to the server. How do you open the firewall?

Answer (score 8):

Log in to AWS - EC2

1. Go to "NETWORK & SECURITY" -> "Security Groups"
2. Find the group your instance is a part of
3. Click on "Inbound"
4. Add the HTTP port 80
5. Apply the changes.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Answer (score -2):

Managed to fix it after starting from scratch. Turns out that I needed to make a new vpc to run everything properly.

Comment: a new VPC has nothing to do with